# extract the main heading from the image using openCV and Tesseract in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, image-processing, tesseract

[image: this is the input image]

now i want to use openCV and tesseract to extract the title of the image.

Expected Output --

[ Demo Pharma Distributors ]

Please Help

Comment: Do you have any code we can work with?

Comment: not yet. code is what am looking for

Comment: well I can give you my code I was wokring with earlier but you will need to work with it.

Comment: Yes sure, give me. I'll look forward to it,.

Answer (score 0):

As I said, the code was used for something else but I think it can give you a nice piece of code to work with.

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import ImageGrab
from PIL import Image
import cv2
import time
import pytesseract

p1 = 520
p2 = 760
p3 = 1450
p4 = 830

# Those points are pixel points you will need to adjust for your frame 


while(True):
        frame = np.array(ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(p1 ,p2 , p3, p4)))
        frame = cv2.bitwise_not(frame)
        cv2.imshow("window", frame)
        pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'Path\to\tesseract.exe'
        txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(frame)
        str_num = re.findall(r'.*', txt)
        print(txt)
        print(str_num)
        print("-----------")
        if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break
```